# Scramble data ONLY within a particular column, other columns unchanged

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to UPDATE a table / records in a column. I would like to SHUFFLE / SCRAMBLE everything ONLY within a column. All other columns will remain the same.

Below is an example

Table name: `Scrambtable`

```
     Title  Firstname    Lastname      Telephone    other columns...
1    Mr     Adam          Smith        001   
2    Mrs    Angela                     002  
3    Mr     Bill          Mowny        003 
4    Miss   Dame                       004   
5    Mr     Boya          Mala
```

I am interested in transforming it as per below

```
     Title  Firstname    Lastname      Telephone    other columns...
1    Mr     Adam           Mala        001   
2    Mrs    Angela                     002  
3    Mr     Bill                       003 
4    Miss   Dame           Smith       004   
5    Mr     Boya           Towny
```

I tried to use the script below..it seems to have only shuffle one 2 lastnames out of the 600 lastname in the lastname column.

```
update  t1
set t1.lastname=b.lastname
from Scrambtable t1
cross apply
(select  top 1  t2.lastname
from 
Scrambtable t2
where
t1.lastname<>t2.lastname
order by newid()
)b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One strategy here is to use a CTE which adds a row number, assigned in a random order.  Then join the CTE to itself on the random row number and assign the last name.

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS ROW
    FROM Scrambtable
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS ROW
    FROM Scrambtable
)

UPDATE t1
SET t1.Lastname = t2.Lastname
FROM CTE1 t1
INNER JOIN CTE2 t2
    ON t1.ROW = t2.ROW
```

Comment: I am getting the error     Incorrect syntax near ';'.   and when I remove the ; at the beginning of WITH, I get the error    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @optimisteve I think I fixed the syntax errors, please try it again.

Comment: Thanks again...just executed the changed script..here is the error this time    Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 61
Invalid object name 'CTE'.

Comment: thank you sir for the effort..works like charm. Question for you. 1. How come you did not add 'WITH' to CTE2.

Comment: @optimisteve Oracle's syntax does not require (nor apparently allow) it.